# linux kernel, userspace buffers, do access_ok and wait create a race condition?

Tags: linux, kernel, race-condition, virtual-memory

In the following code (the `read` implementation for a char driver), is it possible for MMU TLB entries to change during `wait_event_interruptible`, such that `__put_user` causes an exception even though `access_ok` succeeded?

Is it possible to lock the user buffer such that it remains valid for the duration of the request?

Would repeating the `access_ok` check after `wait_event_interruptible` returns make this safe?

```
ssize_t mydriver_pkt_read( struct file* filp, char __user* const buff, size_t count, loff_t* offp )
{
  struct mydriver_pkt_private* priv;
  volatile unsigned short* iobase;
  unsigned next;
  char __user* p = buff;

  if (count <= 0) return -EINVAL;
  if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, buff, count)) return -EFAULT;

  priv = (struct mydriver_pkt_private*)filp->private_data;
  iobase = priv->iobase;

  next = priv->retained;
  if ((next & PKTBUF_FLAG_NOTEMPTY) == 0) {
    next = ioread16(iobase);
    if ((next & PKTBUF_FLAG_NOTEMPTY) == 0) { // no data, start blocking read
      iowrite16(1, iobase); // enable interrupts
      if (wait_event_interruptible(priv->wait_for_ringbuffer, (priv->retained & PKTBUF_FLAG_NOTEMPTY)))
          return -ERESTARTSYS;
      next = priv->retained;
    }
  }

  while (count > 0) {
    __put_user( (char)next, p );
    p++;
    count--;
    next = ioread16(iobase);
    if ((next & PKTBUF_FLAG_STARTPKT) || !(next & PKTBUF_FLAG_NOTEMPTY)) {
      priv->retained = next;
      return (p - buff);
    }
  }

  /* discard remainder of packet */
  do {
    next = ioread16(iobase);
  } while ((next & PKTBUF_FLAG_NOTEMPTY) && !(next & PKTBUF_FLAG_STARTPKT));
  priv->retained = next;
  return (p - buff);
}
```

Exclusive open code:

```
int mydriver_pkt_open( struct inode* inode, struct file* filp )
{
  struct mydriver_pkt_private* priv;

  priv = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct mydriver_pkt_private, cdevnode);

  if (atomic_cmpxchg(&priv->inuse, 0, 1))
    return -EBUSY;

  nonseekable_open(inode, filp);

  filp->private_data = priv;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, you might want to protect your driver with a semaphore. What happens if two processes race in a single read? It looks to me like they can race in such a way that one is left sleeping with device-side interrupts disabled...

Comment: @bdonlan: This is an embedded system: one processor, one hardware thread.  And there is only one instance of the device (enforced during open, see edit).  I guess it would still be possible to get simultaneous requests using `fork` or threads, but the user-mode application isn't multithreaded.  I probably should make it threadsafe anyway.

Comment: Ah, if it's exclusive-open, it won't be a problem, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have the mm_sem semaphore held, page tables can change at any time (by other threads of the same process unmapping pages from a different processor, or by evictions from page reclaim processes). You don't even need to sleep; it can happen even if you have preemption disabled, as long as the TLB shootdown interrupt can arrive. And it can happen even if interrupts are disabled, if you have a SMP machine, as you can, sometimes, see page table updates reflected even without an explicit TLB flush.

`access_ok()` only checks that the range of addresses [does not overlap with kernel space](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h#L60). So it doesn't tell you anything about whether the page table entries allow access - but its result also does not change, even if you block. If access is denied, `__put_user()` will return `-EFAULT`, which must be propagated to userspace (ie, error out here with `-EFAULT`).

Note that the only difference between `put_user()` and `__put_user()` is that `put_user()` performs an `access_ok()` check as well. So if you're using it in a loop, doing a single `access_ok()` ahead of time and using `__put_user()` is probably the right thing to do.